# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "auto_id" of relation "university_university" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am getting a integrity error, I have tried adding `null=True` to auto id field then its working but `auto_id` field must not be `blank=True` or `null=True`.These models are given by my superiors I am finding this hard to understand

This is the core app **models.py**

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Max
from django.utils import timezone
from decimal import Decimal
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from core.utils import DictField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime


def basedata(self, request):
    # Check is create
    if self._state.adding:
        self.auto_id = (self.__class__.objects.aggregate(max_auto_id=Max('auto_id')).get('max_auto_id') or 0) + 1
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.creator = request.user

    # If updating
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        self.updater = request.user
    self.date_updated = timezone.now()


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    auto_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), blank=True, related_name="creator_%(class)s_objects", limit_choices_to={'is_active': True}, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updater = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), blank=True, related_name="updater_%(class)s_objects", limit_choices_to={'is_active': True}, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def delete(self):
        self.is_deleted = True
        self.save()

    def delete_with_user(self, user):
        self.is_deleted = True
        user = self.user
        user.username = user.username + '_deleted_' + str(self.id)
        user.save()
        self.save()

    @property
    def date_added_natural(self):
        return naturaltime(self.date_added)



class Mode(models.Model):
    readonly = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    maintenance = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    down = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mode'
        verbose_name = _('mode')
        verbose_name_plural = _('mode')
        ordering = ('id',)

    class Admin:
        list_display = ('id', 'readonly', 'maintenance', 'down')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class AppUpdate(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    app_version = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    force_upgrade = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recommended_upgrade = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    ios_app_version = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ios_force_upgrade = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ios_recommended_upgrade = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_update'
        verbose_name = _('App update')
        verbose_name_plural = _('App updates')
        ordering = ('id',)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

This is the **university models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from core.models import BaseModel

from versatileimagefield.fields import VersatileImageField

# Create your models here.
class Graduation(BaseModel):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'university_graduation'
        verbose_name = ('Graduation')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Graduation')
        ordering = ('auto_id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class University(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location_url = models.URLField()
    estd = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    ranking = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    intake = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    acceptance_rate = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    teacher_ratio = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    about_university = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    graduation = models.ManyToManyField(Graduation)
    logo = VersatileImageField('Logo', upload_to="university/logo")
    image = VersatileImageField('Image', upload_to="university/image")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'university_university'
        verbose_name = ('University')
        verbose_name_plural = ('University')
        ordering = ('auto_id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
    
class AdmissionRequirments(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    auto_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, limit_choices_to={'is_deleted': False}, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requirement = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'university_admission_requirements'
        verbose_name = ('Admission Requirements')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Admission Requirements')
        ordering = ('auto_id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Scholarship(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    eligibility = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    applicability = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    graduation = models.ManyToManyField(Graduation)
    university = models.ManyToManyField(University)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'university_scholarship'
        verbose_name = ('Scholarship')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Scholarship')
        ordering = ('auto_id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

This is the university **form.py**

```
from django.forms import forms
from university.models import University, Graduation
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user

class CreateUniversityForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = University
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self):
        user = self.cleaned_data.get("user")
        university = University(
                        auto_id = self.cleaned_data.get('id'),
                        title = self.cleaned_data.get('title'),
                        location = self.cleaned_data.get('location'),
                        location_url = self.cleaned_data.get('location_url'),
                        estd = self.cleaned_data.get('estd'),
                        ranking = self.cleaned_data.get('ranking'),
                        intake = self.cleaned_data.get('intake'),
                        acceptance_rate = self.cleaned_data.get('acceptance_rate'),
                        teacher_ratio = self.cleaned_data.get('teacher_ratio'),
                        about_university = self.cleaned_data.get('about_university'),
                        description = self.cleaned_data.get('description'),
                        logo = self.cleaned_data.get('logo'),
                        image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
        )

        graduation = Graduation.objects.get(name=self.cleaned_data.get("graduation"))
        university.set_graduation = graduation

        university.set_creator = user
        university.set_updator = user
        university.save()

        return university
```

This is my university **view.py** to create a university

```
def create_university(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = get_user(request)
        logo = request.FILES.get('logo')
        image = request.FILES.get('image')
        auto_id = int(request.POST.get('id'))
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        graduation = "berlin"
        location = request.POST.get('location')
        location_url = request.POST.get('location_url')
        established = request.POST.get('established')
        ranking = request.POST.get('ranking')
        intake = request.POST.get('intake')
        acceptance_rate = request.POST.get('acceptance')
        teacher_ratio = request.POST.get('teacher')
        about_university = request.POST.get('about')
        description = request.POST.get('description')

        data = {
            'user': user,
            'title': title,
            'id': auto_id,
            'location': location,
            'location_url': location_url,
            'estd': established,
            'ranking': ranking,
            'intake': intake,
            'acceptance_rate': acceptance_rate,
            'teacher_ratio': teacher_ratio,
            'about_university': about_university,
            'description': description,
            'logo': logo,
            'image': image,
            'graduation': graduation}

        print(data)

        create_university_form = CreateUniversityForm(data=data)

        if create_university_form.is_valid():
            university = create_university_form.save()
            context = {
                'title': university.title
            }
            
            return JsonResponse(context)
        else:
            context = {
                "validationerror": "validation error"
            }
            return JsonResponse(context)
```

[university model admin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZljtR.png)

**All i wanted to do is to create a new univerisity object but this auto_id is killing me, also i cant understand this BaseModel system**

```
  File "C:\Users\abinp\Documents\projects\tegain\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "auto_id" of relation "university_university" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (c496cf2f-2966-49f3-b2d4-9efa4f3323b4, null, 2022-08-08 10:36:59.869385+00, 2022-08-08 10:36:59.869385+00, f, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, , , null, null).
```

Comment: Why do you need to use  2 fields `auto_id` and `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you have a null value in the ID column.

```py
auto_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True, unique=True)
```

You have `PositiveIntegerField`, that means that you have to fill it and you're probably not doing that in forms. For ID you should always use `AutoField`.

So it returns null because there is nothing in your auto_id variable. I think replace this with `AutoField` should solve the problem.

Documentation search for `AutoField`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/

Comment: But i have already a id in my database, The thing is univerisity model is extending from core model it has already a id and i dont know why this auto_id is for